# How do I collapse SQL in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked the documentation for [code collapsing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding), many languages have a marker defined but SQL doesn't.

SQL Server Management Studio recognizes `begin` and `end` as a region, allowing for folding, but VS Code doesn't.

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone coming here for the answer.
Region markers for `SQL` have been added to VS CODE in 2019 and you can now use them as:

```
--#region [name region if you like]
part of code you want to fold/collapse
--#endregion
```

Then use `Ctrl + Shift + P` or `View -> Command Palette...` and choose `Fold All Regions`.

Comment: Classic but still magic. Abracadabra!✨

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to work for me. Using v1.84.0-insider on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

use tab for group common code.
For example:
BEGIN 
   YOU SQL CODE
END

the region between BEGIN will be collapsed