# How to have collapsable regions in sql in visual studio code

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I am working on a big sql query and I have some columns that come from different tables. It would be a lot of help if I could have collapsable regions for those columns. After searching online I tried that but it did not work

```
select
--#region reg1
age,
--#endregion
--#region reg2
surname
--#endregion
from
my_table;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935058/how-do-i-collapse-sql-in-vs-code

Comment: That is where I took my snippet from. Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Your example works fine for my VS Code - V 1.83.1 default configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax,

```
--#region <<RegionName>>
<<SQL Statements>>
--#endregion
```

[Collapsed SQL statements for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziVZj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the query has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77730705/6908861

One additional info, that might be helpful: 
You can use `Ctrl + Shift + P` or View -> Command Palette... and choose `Fold All Regions.`